# How to predict based on one instance using keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction, tweets

I  created a model (h5) to predict the class of tweet (negative or positive).  I can predict based on all test data using this code:

```
    MAX_NB_WORDS = 20000
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(liste)
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(liste)
    MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 400
    X_processed = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    predicts=model.predict(X_processed)
```

where **liste** is a list of tweets.
But when it comes  to predict based on one instance(one tweet) this method doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: how about replacing liste with list consist of one tweet ?

Comment: @YukiShioriii Thank you so much , that did work. I don't know why I didn't think of doing that LOL.Thanks